# vue,js combine transform :scale,translate and transformOrigin to zoom and move div

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, scale

using vue code to scale and move div, there is a problem when using the mouse wheel to zoom div, move div everything work perfectly but when zoom theres is a problem the div keeps moving unexpectable , the aim for code is to scale and move div and keep zooming where mouse is pointing

```
<template>
  <div class="container-w">
    <div
      class="movable-div"
      ref="movableDiv"
      @mousedown="startDrag"
      @mousemove="handleDrag"
      @mouseup="stopDrag"
      @mouseleave="stopDrag"
      @wheel.prevent="handleZoom"
      :style="divStyle"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isDragging: false,
      initialMouseX: 0,
      initialMouseY: 0,
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      transformOriginX: 0,
      transformOriginY: 0,
      zoomFactor: 1,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    divStyle() {
      return {
        transformOrigin: `${this.transformOriginX}px ${this.transformOriginY}px`,
        transform: `translate(${this.offsetX}px, ${this.offsetY}px) scale(${this.zoomFactor})`,
        background: "blue",
        width: "500px",
        height: "500px",
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    startDrag(event) {
      this.isDragging = true;
      this.initialMouseX = event.clientX - this.offsetX;
      this.initialMouseY = event.clientY - this.offsetY;
    },
    handleDrag(event) {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        const deltaX = event.clientX - this.initialMouseX;
        const deltaY = event.clientY - this.initialMouseY;
        this.offsetX = deltaX;
        this.offsetY = deltaY;
      }
    },
    stopDrag() {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        this.isDragging = false;
      }
    },
    handleZoom(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const scaleFactor = event.deltaY > 0 ? 0.9 : 1.1;
      this.zoomFactor *= scaleFactor;

      this.transformOriginX = event.offsetX;
      this.transformOriginY = event.offsetY;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.container-w {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.movable-div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: grab;
}
</style>
```

expcet to work zoom perfectly